# Grouped routes in multiple controllers in Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, silex, symfony4

I'm rewriting my Silex-based application to Symfony 4, as the Silex will be deprecated in a while from now. Everything works great so far, but I have a problem with nested routes.

I had lots of nested (child routes) in Silex application with different controllers assigned to them.

```
$app->match('/api', function (ControllerCollection $api) {
    $api->get('/homepage', 'ControllerOne::index');
    $api->get('/contact', 'ControllerTwo::index');
});
```

This was pretty easy in Silex, but now in Symfony 4, I'm using annotations for the routes' management and it seems like I can't find a way to group those routes.

It's annoying especially when it comes to routes with `_locale` as the syntax for those routes is pretty long and still.. it's not a good way to have it everywhere in case I need to change the `_locale` prefix some day to something like `/home/{_locale}/`.

```
ControllerOne extends Controller 
{
    /**
     * @Route("/{_locale}/",
     *     name="root",
     *     methods="GET",
     *     requirements={"_locale": "en|fr"}
     * )
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index(): Response
    {
        return $this->render('some.html.twig');
    }
}

ControllerTwo extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/{_locale}/homepage",
     *     name="homepage",
     *     methods="GET",
     *     requirements={"_locale": "en|fr"}
     * )
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index(): Response
    {
        return $this->render('some2.html.twig');
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I had an idea to create some sort of `PrefixedController` where I'd specify the prefix over the class and the extend that `PrefixedController` instead of the basic `Controller`, but it seems to don't work.

```
/**
 * @Route("/{_locale}", requirements={"_locale": "en|fr"})
 */
controller PrefixedController extends Controller 
{
}

controller ControllerOne extends PrefixedController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", methods="GET")
     * @Return Response
     */
    public function index(): Response 
    {
        return $this->render('some.html.twig');
    }
}
```

But when I navigate to `/en/` it can't match the route.

Comment: Look at routing prefix option, it should work in the same way than Silex.

Comment: As far as the locale issue goes, you can use parameters to simplify some of the stuff: https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/service_container_parameters.html  Don't think that is really a general solution for you though.

Comment: @Cerad thanks for that. It partially solves an issue with `_locale` and some prefixes, but I guess it's not the best solution as the prefixes can't be generated with dynamic variables for example. But it surely is better than nothing, thanks once again.

Comment: Might be better off just defining your routes in yaml files.  Then, in the extremely unlikely event you decide to change all your routes, you will just have a couple of files to edit.  And I suspect you might be over thinking things a bit.

Comment: @Cerad Yep. I agree with you about the yaml files and the pros of doing it in one file in case of something changes and I might be overthinking things a bit, but it surely would be a nice feature to add as I used it a lot in Silex and it give you more freedom actually to split up your files a bit more etc.

Comment: @DawidZbiński could this work for you https://github.com/symfony/demo/blob/master/config/routes/annotations.yaml#L4 ?

Comment: @yceruto Yeah, this works for me. But it is not actually my concern.  The prefix works fine, I just need to add it to multiple controllers and I wanted to do it in one place. In your example I'd need to add `prefix: /{_locale}` to each and every controller if I'm not mistaken

Comment: In [this example](https://github.com/symfony/demo/blob/master/config/routes/annotations.yaml#L4) you're adding the prefix for all controllers within `'../src/Controller/'` that isn't what you need?

Comment: I'll take a look at it in a couple of minutes and let you know.

Comment: @yceruto Great, it works. Thank you very much. You may consider adding it as an answer and write a bit more about it, I'd then mark this as correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done in the main routing file where the routing resources are imported. In Symfony 4 it is in `config/routes/annotations.yaml`. Then to provide a prefix `/{_locale}` for the imported routes uses the `prefix` option:

```
# config/routes/annotations.yaml
controllers:
    resource: '../src/Controller/'
    type: annotation
    prefix: /{_locale}
```

The path of each route being loaded from the new routing resource will now be prefixed with the placeholder `/{_locale}`.